# How to debug MPI functions (MPICH) in external processes?

Tags: debugging, mpi, mpich

I'am replacing the POSIX that is working in the MPI-function with other means, but having trouble with debugging the external process. 
I am changing the functions that are from  **utils/sock/sock.c** in MPI library (hydra)

```
HYDU_sock_write //changing the source code 
HYDU_sock_read  //changing the source code

HYD_status HYDU_sock_read(int fd, void *buf, int maxlen, int *recvd, int *closed,
                          enum HYDU_sock_comm_flag flag)
HYD_status HYDU_sock_write(int fd, const void *buf, int maxlen, int *sent, int *closed,
                           enum HYDU_sock_comm_flag flag)
```

For example, when I try to run the test source code below with **node1 and node2** I can see that two main processes are initiated, and one runs in the node1 and the other runs in the node2.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Initialize the MPI environment
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  // Find out rank, size
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  // We are assuming at least 2 processes for this task
  if (world_size < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "World size must be greater than 1 for %s\n", argv[0]);
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
  }

  int number;
  if (world_rank == 0) {
    // If we are rank 0, set the number to -1 and send it to process 1
    number = -1;
    MPI_Send(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  } else if (world_rank == 1) {
    MPI_Recv(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Process 1 received number %d from process 0\n", number);
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The problem is I can debug the first process in node1, and I successfully changed all the source code in the MPI function. However I haven't got a clue how I can debug the second process which runs in node2 (external host).

My question is.. 
Is there a good way to debug the second process that runs in the external host? I have tried the printf function but this also only runs in the first process which runs in the node1 and does not show anything in node2.

Comment: This is what parallel debuggers are for ! DDT or TotalView can do that, these are commercial software though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Is there any debugging mode for monitoring processes that run on external servers? because I only see the features for checking multiple threads that are running in the internal host, not the external ones.

Comment: I only use DDT, just tell the debugger this is a MPI app, and it will automagically attach all the tasks once `MPI_Init()` completes.

Comment: You don't even mention the platform so I can't give a good specific answer. In general: go to the external host and attach a debugger to the MPI process.